# iOS - Firebase Crash Reporting issue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I have gone through this doc line by line.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios

And I got the crash reported **successfully.**

**But** when I uploaded my code to git , other user get crash complaining upload-sym.

Because doc says to add the following to run script:

```
# Replace this with the GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file
GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:my:app:id

# Replace the /Path/To/ServiceAccount.json with the path to the key you just downloaded
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "/Path/To/ServiceAccount.json"
```

---

I guess the error is due to that path to my private key "ServiceAccount.json"

Because I have my own path for that private key , but the another person will get my path to private key which is not possible .

**So, can anyone tell where should I place that private key to excuse this error.**

Answer (score 2):

[image: Place your serviceAccount.json on the same directory as of your xcode project or workspace]Place your ServiceAccount.json to root of your project,

and then give path as

```
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "$SRCROOT/ServiceAccount.json"
```

This will work for all your users.
Although it is not recommended to share your ServiceAccount.json to other user other than your team members.